# Вычисление экспоненты

Tags: c

Вычисляю экспоненту по формуле Тейлора:

```
long double cust_exp(double x) {
    long double rememberX = x;
    long double returnValue = 1. + x;
   /* for (int k = 2; k <= 150; k++) {
        x = x * rememberX;
        returnValue = returnValue + x/fact(k);
    }*/
    returnValue = 1;
    for (int i = 150; i > 0; --i) {
        returnValue = 1. + x * returnValue / i;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

```html
long double fact(int k) {
    long double n = 1;
    long double returnValue = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        n = n * i;
    }
    returnValue = n;
    return returnValue;
}
```

Закоменченное это то же самое через факториал, только из-за факториала дольше. Нужно с точностью до 6ти знаков после запятой по сравнению с оригинальной функцией. Но вот при степенях больше 20 начинаются расхождения уже на 6м знаке. Есть ли какой-то другой способ расчёта, более точный?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос определение `fact`.

Comment: Добавил факториал

Answer (score 1):

***NB:*** скорее всего все версии достаточно точны. Проблема в том что `double` не может представлять большие числа достаточно точно.

Так будет точнее:

```
double exp_(double x) {
    double sum = 1;
    double term = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 150; ++i) {
        term *= x / i;
        sum += term;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Ещё лучше для больших экспонент использовать формулу *e<sup>x</sup> = (e<sup>x/2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>*.

Проанализируем ошибку для *x = 22*.

> ```
> exp (22) = 3584912846.13159179687500000000
> exp_(22) = 3584912846.13159275054931640625
> разница  = 9.5367431640625 * 10^-7
> относительная ошибка: 2.66 * 10^-16
> ```

Это очень маленькая ошибка. Например, относительная ошибка между соседними вещественными числами равна `2.22 * 10^-16`. То есть, наша функция почти рядом с библиотечной, отличаются только два последних бита мантиссы.

Comment: Вроде с формулой с делением на 2 только хуже становится. На степени 22 уже на 6м знаке различия.

Comment: Числа покажите.

Comment: 21.600000........ 0.0000019073486328125. Первое это степень, второе разница между оригинальным exp и функцией. 21.700000...... 0.0000042915344238281250000000000000000000. Это с делением х на 2.

Comment: Относительная ошибка 2.66e-16. При том что минимальная относительная ошибка `double` 2.22e-16. Очень достойный результат.

Comment: Добавил в ответ оценку ошибки.